# Updated Individual Rows in PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am retriving data from a SQL DB which I am stroring in a form. I have a update page however, I dont know how I can update table according to what the user wishes to change and hence update the database.

This is what I mean. Say after running the query I have the output :

```
Product  | Descption  | Quantity   | Price   | StartDate  | End Date
chcolates   xyz           2.0         4.99     2013-03-11    2013-03-20      
sweets      yum!          1.0         1.99     2013-03-15    2013-03-27
```

so this is being outputted as a table in php by queuing the db.(i.e. this seller is selling 2 products mentioned).

Now say the user wanted to update the first row and change the quantity for example. Then how can I do this? I know I can use the SQL QUERY UPDATE TABLE sellers WHERE ??

Should I output a table or a form? The user is able to update any row they wish and any field also. (i.e. can update the product they wish to sell, descp, quantity etc.)

How can I go about doing something like this? Any ideas please?

**====EDIT======**
Thanks for everyones suggestions. I have a formatting error. I am inside my php tags and after running the query as such:

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($querySellers)){
echo 'Product:'.'<br />'.'<input type="text" value = $rows[\'ProductName\']>';
```

This does not seem to be printing the VALUE of the query from the DB and instead prints

```
$rows['ProductName']
```

inside the text box this is a formatting error right? What can I do to solve this? And also initially the productName is a drop down combo box... Is there a way I can do it so that when I run the query the output is shown as the SELECTED combo box option?

Thanks once again.

Comment: You need to (somehow) pass the unique identifier of the row you wish to update. That's why primary keys were invented and that's why you can usually see some numbers or series of characters being passed via GET method in forms. That goes as far as *how*. Now in terms of actually implementing the idea - well, that's the fun part to discover so I'll skip that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing you should do is implement an `ID` column (auto increment maybe?) or some unique identifier (`Primary Key`) to the items in the table. This way, you can easily edit one item by doing

```
UPDATE table SET value = 'value' WHERE id = $id
```

In your case, you do not have any unique identifier so you would have to build a large `WHERE` statement to include everything ie.

```
WHERE Product = 'chocolates' AND Description = 'xyz' AND .. AND..
```

and this may not be entirely unique.

**EDIT**: (in reference to edit)
The problem is how PHP handles single quotes vs. double quotes. PHP will **NOT** evaluate variables in single quotes but will in double quotes.

```
$myvar = "value";
echo '$myvar'; // output: $myvar
echo "$myvar"; // output: value
```

So you need to change your construction

```
echo "Product: <br /> <input type=\"text\" value = \"{$rows['ProductName']}\">";
```

Notice the change of single quotes to double and the escaping of the double quotes.
As for your question on the selected option. You need a way to determine which is selected and add an `IF` statement with the code to add `Selected` attribute to the option.

Comment: You will have to loop through the returned items to build the table. You will also have to include the `ID` either as a `hidden` field or as a value in the url ie. `edit.php?item=$id` so you know which item is being modified

Comment: Hi, I already have an ID in the sellers table which is AI. The problem is... Each seller when they log in are selling something different. So this seller is selling the two products listed. The problem is.. I think I need to get a form in a while loop.. so say :

` while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($querysellers)){
//output form with data?
Product <select name="products" value="<?=$rows['ProductName']?>
<option value ="1">Chcolate</option>
<option value = "2">sweets</option>
</select>

<input type ="text" name="description" value="<?=rows['Quantity']">

`
I think maybe?

Comment: Basically what I wish to do is ... Retrive the data like I do at the moment. Put this data in a form maybe or table which ever would be better for the user to edit in. Once, the user has edited there fields then use the SQL query update the database. 

The Product Name, start date and end date are all SELECT OPTION fields the rest are all TEXT fields. Does this make senesce?

Comment: You can design it however you want, but it has to contain a way to have the ID of the item being edited. Wether it is editing one by one or a whole group to loop through. You'll have to research the method to best suit your needs.

Comment: Ah, I see thanks I will take a look at this and see what I can do. I think what I am planning is:
Looping through the data and displaying it as a form and then then have a separate update button for each record/row hence, when they click update it updates that specific row.

Comment: Wow that works great. Sorry I didn't know you could do it like that(still a novice at php). Also say originally my product name and date fields are drop down combo boxes such as: 
`
Product:<br /><select name="productName">
<option value="1">chocolate</option>
<option value="2">sweets</option>
</select> 
`  
is there a way I can edit the code so that when the user wishes to update it loads the selected product that is in the DB. So does the same thing its doing now but shows it in combo box with the option selected rather than the text box? Is this possible to do?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help and teaching about the construction of these statements. I will give that a try:)

Comment: Hey buddy. After using your new edit line it seems to be giving an error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING 

I think it might be because of the \ you have not closed it after you open it on value?

Comment: my apologies. please see the line again

Comment: Thanks that works now. I have been working on the drop down box route however it is not showing the combo boxes. I have asked the question here:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391646/select-option-value-from-database-on-selected/) can you please take a quick look and see if you are able to assist please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an id with primary key that auto increaments, not null.
THen

```
UPDATE `your_db_table`.`column_table` SET `Product` 
= 'Sweet Stuff' WHERE 'Product`.`prod_id` = 1 LIMIT 1;
```

Then the rest of the stuff is is clearly explained by @UnholyRanger

Comment: Suggested edit: Remove "LIMIT 1" since, if truely unique, only one item will be considered hence it is not needed.