# select option value from database on selected

Tags: php, mysql, forms, combobox

I have a small problem. I have a edit.php page. This page list the products information that can be edited.

I run a query

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){


echo"<form method=\"POST\" action=\"edit.php\">";
echo "<input type ='hidden' name='ID' value = '{$rows['ID']}'>"; 
echo "Product:&nbsp <input type='text' name='product' value = '{$rows['ProductName']}'>";
```

Before the while loop I store the details in variables as such:

```
$hiddenid = $_POST['ID'];   
$productName = $_POST['product'];
```

and this works. when I load the php form it shows the product name (in a text field) retrieved from the DB. However the problem is I want to store the product name as a drop down list box that has already been selected by the user and then select that.

So, basically what I wish to do is instead of displaying the DB retrieved options in a text box I wish the option the user has selected to be displayed in a dropdown list box.

I hope this makes sence? Why are my option values not showing at all and secondly they are not showing the SELECTED option either (retrieved from the DB).

Any help please?

Comment: You didn't end your foreach loop

Comment: @ioums Sorry about that I have ended it. Just forgot the last } edited it now:)

Comment: Maybe just another typo, but it should be closed before the </select>

Comment: I just dont know why none of the options are showing at all. I am  storing them in the array. And then the SELECTED is based on what has been retrieved from the DB. I don't understand why it is not showing any options let alone the selected option?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @ioums I tried to put the closing } before the </select> however it is still not displaying any options? I really dont know why...

AarolamaBluenk Yes I have heard about these. I will updated my pages once I fix a few issues I have at present:) Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you're getting anything back from your query and that the `while` loop is running?

Comment: @UnholyRanger I had done something really supid which I didn't realise. Before my while loop I had 
 if (isset($_POST['button'])){ 
 $hiddenid = $_POST['ID']; 
 $product = $_POST['ProductName'];
//array here
}
so my array was inside the isset! After I realised it is now outside this isset and just before the while loop. 
what happens now is when I refresh the page.. I can drop down and its showing the 4 options but a BLANK drop down. so you click on it it highlights and you can pick 4 option but not TEXT VALUE ON THE drop down box. Why might this be?

Comment: @UnholyRanger my query is 

SELECT s.ID, s.PID, p.PName, s.Descrip, s.price, s.quantity, s.startdate, s.enddate
         FROM product p, sellers s
         WHERE $idcheck = s.CID AND p.ID = s.PID

Comment: and I know for a fact I am getting rows as the whole thing works perfectly when I use <input type='text' name='products' value='{$rows['ProductName']}'>>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Focusing on this one area, you should be getting a PHP error unless it is a copy error. Notice the following changes:

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
?>
    <form method=\"POST\" action=\"edit.php\">
    <input type ='hidden' name='ID' value = '<?php echo $rows['ID'];?>'>
    <select name ="pnames">
        <?php foreach ($arrayproducts as $key => $value) {
        ?>  
            <option value = "<?php echo $key; ?>" 
            <?php
                if ($key == $productName){
                    echo 'selected="selected"';
                } 
            ?> >
            <?php echo $value; ?> 
            </option>
     <?php } //end foreach ?>   
   </select>
<?php }//end while ?>
```

You had plain HTML code in the PHP segment in the beginning.

Also, I believe you want

```
if ($value == $productName){
```

Comment: Okay I got it working... I decided to do everything within the PHP Tags.. Here is what I mean the error was I was closing the > incorrectly after echoing
`echo"<form method = \"POST\" action =\"edit.php\">";
        echo "<input type ='hidden' name='ID' value = '{$rows['ID']}'>"; 
//  echo "Product: <input type='hidden' name='product' value = '{$rows['ProductName']}'>"; 
  echo "Product: <input type='text' name='PName' value = '{$rows['PID']}'>"; 
echo "<select name =\"pNames\">";
`

Comment: ` foreach ($productsarry as $key => $value) {
   echo"<option value = \"$key\""; 
 if ($key == $productName){
  echo "selected=\"selected\"";
 }echo">";
    echo "$value"; 
    echo "</option>";
    }//end of foreach loop 
   echo"</select>";`

Okay, so at least now the options show. However, another darn problem:'(  

Basically the page shows the first option on the drop down i.e. 'cholcate' and not specifically what the user has saved in the DB. Why might this be. Any ideas?

Comment: was the last line of my answer your problem?

Comment: For the problem of the options not showing up I think it was because I had it like this:
`
 if ($key == $productName){
  echo "selected=\"selected\">";
 };
` then I changed it to :

`if ($key == $productName){
  echo "selected=\"selected\"";
 }echo">"
`
I believe that was the issue why the options were not showing. I will now try and fix that options not showing error using your extra line too.

Comment: Hey buddy I tried that still shows chocolate as the first option. When I use a text box is shows 'sweets' which is the correct answer. however, the selected combobox shows choclate first and then sweets. It is supposed to be default selected to the correct value fm DB:(

Comment: have you checked the HTML output (right click -> view source) to see if the selected is set? Also double check if the `$productName` is equivalent to the `$key` or the `$value`

Comment: Looking at the page source it always seems to be selecting option value 1... Yeah that is evuvalent. Let me show you what I have done...

Comment: Hi please take a look at my edited question which may help you identify why the correct SELECTED options do not show and it default shows the first option in the array. Thank you very much for your help.:)

Comment: I Strongly believe there is a problem somewhere in the IF loop. But the $productName is equvalient to the $key value. Since the key as you can see from the array is 1,2 or 3 and the $productName is also returning the productid which is hidden. I have renamed this variable in the edit to avoid confusion. Do you think it is because the $orginalproductid  is only stored after the button has been clicked? I really cant understand why this is not working:(

Comment: okay here is a small clue if I do this:
 echo"<option value = \"$key\""; 
 if ($key==3){
  echo "selected=\"selected\"";
 }

then it does indeed change the default option to ice-cream! so there is something wrong in what I am comparing.

Comment: FIXED IT!! WOO... basically I changed the thing to $key==$rows['productid']

finally! lol!! thanks so much for your help provided. Really appreciate it... I have one more major thing I'm stuck on but I feel bad to keep asking you :$

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't such a good place for this, but since I see tons of code daily that is horrible I figured I would chime in.

First of all, check your inputs. You should never trust any variables from a user $_GET, $_POST, etc. The looseness of the original code is just looking for an SQL injection attack.

```
<?php
```

This thing looks like it's expecting some sort of passed ID which would then pull the productName from the database... it's really unclear. So we're assuming variables are already defined. Need to use code like this:

```
if(!empty($_GET['id'])&&is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
   $id=$_GET['id'];
} else {
   $id='';
}

//Declare your array
$arrayproducts = array();


while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
```

You need to call something out here for the returned array... without seeing the SQL it's hard to say what you're expecting, but your callouts should look like this...

```
//Whatever the name from SQL is for the column
$temp_ID = $rows['id'];

//Whatever the name for the product column is
$temp_Prod = $rows['prod'];

//Load the array
$arrayproducts[$temp_ID]=$temp_Prod;
}
```

It's best to load a var for everything and then post it in one shot rather than in and out of PHP. The code will be much faster and you'll be able to keep track of the code.

```
$page = "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"edit.php\">";
```

Check to see if that ID worked. Regex would be best, but one thing at a time here.

```
if(!empty($id)){
    $page .= "<input type =\"hidden\" name=\"ID\" value = \"$id\">";
} 
$page .= "<select name =\"pnames\">\n";

foreach ($arrayproducts as $key => $value) {

   $page .= "<option value = \"$key\"";
```

It's best to use the auto-increment fields and built-in IDs for mysql so there isn't a chance of having a duplicate ID taking over an existing record.

```
      if ($id == $key){
        $page .= ' selected="selected"';
      }
   $page .= ">$value</option>\n";

//close the foreach
}

$page .= "</select>\n"; 

print $page;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply and help. I have fixed it now and it was because of how I was closing one small '>' inside the echo !!! Outrageous right? The problem now is the SELECTED doesn't show based on what the users original choice was:'(